# Invalid object access c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, constructor, copy

I was trying to run this code from the Stroustroup's C++ book, there is some code which I added as everything was not available in the book. I keep hitting the following problem. I know there are multiple questions here on the same error, but my code is different and hence this question.

The error is

> copy(5826,0x7fff76b09300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff6a9404c18: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   Abort trap: 6

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class Vector {
private:
    double * elem; // elem points to an array of sz doubles
    int sz;
public:
    Vector(int s) {
        sz = s;
        elem = new double[sz];
        for (int i = 0; i<sz; i++) {
            elem[i] = i;
        }
    }
    ~Vector() { delete[] elem; } // destructor: release resources
    Vector(const Vector& a); // copy constructor
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& a); // copy assignment
    double& operator[](int i);
    const double& operator[](int i) const;
    int size() const;
};


Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) // copy constr uctor
{
    elem = new double[sz], // allocate space for elements
        sz = a.sz;
    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) // copy elements
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}


double& Vector::operator[](int k) {
    return this->elem[k];
}


Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& a) // copy assignment
{
    double* p = new double[a.sz];
    for (int i = 0; i != a.sz; ++i)
        p[i] = a.elem[i];
    delete[] elem; // delete old elements
    elem = p;
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;
}


int main() {
    Vector v1(10);
    Vector v2 = v1;
    v1[0] = 2;
    v2[1] = 3;
    cout << v1[0] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor should reverse two lines, because you didn't set a value for `sz` yet.

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) // copy constructor
{
    elem = new double[sz];
    sz = a.sz;
    for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}
```

So you could do

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) // copy constructor
{
    sz = a.sz;
    elem = new double[sz];
    for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor has a bug:

```
elem = new double[sz], // allocate space for elements
```

This is using the `sz` of the object you are creating, and `sz` in this case hasn't been initialized yet.  It should be:

```
elem = new double[a.sz], // allocate space for elements
```

I'd also recommend staying away from using commas too, and change it to

```
elem = new double[a.sz];//<--semicolon instead of comma
```

Comment: Thank you, this one got away from my attention and it was really hard to find this one with the error message I got, why would system throw this error?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the copy constructor.    `sz` is uninitialised when being used in the statement `elem = new double[sz]`, so accessing its value causes undefined behaviour.   Presumably you intended the statement to be `elem = new double[a.sz]`.

A result of this is that, in `main()`, the definition/initialisation `Vector v2 = v1` yields undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This copy constructor is invalid

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) // copy constr uctor
{
    elem = new double[sz], // allocate space for elements
        sz = a.sz;
    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) // copy elements
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}
```

At first you bave to set sz or to use `a.sz` in the operator new.

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) // copy constr uctor
{
    sz = a.sz;
    elem = new double[sz], // allocate space for elements

    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) // copy elements
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}
```

Take into account that it is better to define data member `sz` as having type `size_t` instead of `int`.